# jquery get selected value from multiple dropdown lists with same ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example I have couple of dropdown lists

```
<select id="selectList">
    <option value="0">Value 0</option>
    <option value="1">Value 1</option>
</select>
<select id="selectList">
    <option value="0">Value 0</option>
    <option value="1">Value 1</option>
</select>
```

so now I want to alert each list's selected value, how should I do it, because I can't understand how to do this.

this is my code snippet:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#selectList').change(function () {
         if ($(this).val() == 0)
             alert("call the do something function on option 0");
         if ($(this).val() == 1)
             alert("call the do something function on option 1");
     });
 });
```

Comment: Identifiers must be uniuqe

Comment: use unique 'id`

Comment: You can't use multiple id, maybe you should use class instead

Answer (score 1):

Use `class` instead `id` like this:

HTML (note that I changed the select id's for classes):

```
<select class="selectList">
    <option value="0">Value 0</option>
    <option value="1">Value 1</option>
</select>
<select class="selectList">
    <option value="0">Value 0</option>
    <option value="1">Value 1</option>
</select>
```

Javascript (same as HTML, changed the #id for the .class):

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('.selectList').change(function () {
         if ($(this).val() == 0)
             alert("call the do something function on option 0");
         if ($(this).val() == 1)
             alert("call the do something function on option 1");
     });
 });
```

Working example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#selectList').change(function () {
         if ($(this).val() == 0)
             alert("call the do something function on option 0");
         if ($(this).val() == 1)
             alert("call the do something function on option 1");
     });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectList">
    <option value="0">Value 0</option>
    <option value="1">Value 1</option>
</select>
<select id="selectList">
    <option value="0">Value 0</option>
    <option value="1">Value 1</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use unique `id` for your elements in DOM. However in you case you can make it a `class` instead,

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.selectList').change(function() {
     if ($(this).val() == 0)
       alert("call the do something function on option 0");
     if ($(this).val() == 1)
       alert("call the do something function on option 1");
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="selectList">
  <option value="0">Value 0</option>
  <option value="1">Value 1</option>
</select>
<select class="selectList">
  <option value="0">Value 0</option>
  <option value="1">Value 1</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

`ID` of each `element` must be `unique` .You can assign same class to both `select` and bind event using `class` selector

```
<select class="select">
    <option value="0">Value 0</option>
    <option value="1">Value 1</option>
</select>
<select class="select">
    <option value="0">Value 0</option>
    <option value="1">Value 1</option>
</select>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.select').change(function () {
   if ($(this).val() == "0")
     alert("call the do something function on option 0");
   if ($(this).val() == "1")
      alert("call the do something function on option 1");
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use different id name for both select and same class name for both select after that you can do this.

```
<select class="selectlist" id="selectList1">
   <option value="0">Value 0</option>
   <option value="1">Value 1</option>
</select>
<select class="selectlist"  id="selectList2">
   <option value="0">Value 0</option>
   <option value="1">Value 1</option>
</select>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.selectList').change(function () {
     if ($(this).val() == 0)
         alert("call the do something function on option 0");
     if ($(this).val() == 1)
         alert("call the do something function on option 1");
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

in your case, you can do something like this, by using same name attribute to get the values or event separately for each.

```
var lists = document.getElementByClassName('select') //return all elements with this class name

// using index can be accessed seprately each
alert($(lists[0]).val())
alert($(lists[1]).val())
```